# Getting error in php image uploader

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am getting following error in this code which got resolve..!

Here is the pastebin link to see the whole code : http://pastebin.com/JKegmNHC

Also here is the code also available.. you can see it through here or using the pastebin link to get the error indication right from the related line....

Here is the code :

```
    <?php

$submit=$_POST['sub'];
if(isset($submit))
{
$name=$_FILES['img']['name'];
$type=$_FILES['img']['type'];

$size=($_FILES['img']['size'])/1024;

$ext=end(explode('.',$name));
if (($ext == "gif")
|| ($ext == "jpeg")
|| ($ext == "jpg")
|| ($ext =="png")
&& ($size > 30))
{


############################## File Renaming ###################################################

$newname=uniqid();
//$ext=end(explode('.',$name));
$fullname=$newname.".".$ext;
$target="pics/";
$fulltarget=$target.$fullname;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],$fulltarget))
{
echo "Success";
}
else
{
echo "Failed";
}
############################## File Renaming end ###################################################
}
else{
echo "not successful";
}
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="abhi.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Php Image Uploader</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="a1">
<form name="frm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="img" /><br />

<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Store" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="a2">

<?php echo "
<html>
<head>
<title>Aviary Photo Editer</title>
<!-- Load Feather code -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://feather.aviary.com/js/feather.js'></script>
<!-- Instantiate Feather -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
var featherEditor = new Aviary.Feather({
apiKey: 'ceegvx4siylhayrr',
apiVersion: 3,
theme: 'dark', // Check out our new 'light' and 'dark' themes!
tools: 'enhance,frames,crop,orientation,brightness,saturation,sharpness,draw,redeye,blemish,effects,stickers,resize,focus,contrast,warmth,colorsplash,text,whiten',
appendTo: '',
onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
    var img = document.getElementById(imageID);
    img.src = newURL;
},
onError: function(errorObj) {
    alert(errorObj.message);
}
});
function launchEditor(id, src) {
featherEditor.launch({
    image: id,
    url: src
 });
return false;
}
 </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id='injection_site'></div>

<img id='image1' src='$fulltarget'/>

<p><input type='image' src='http://images.aviary.com/images/edit-photo.png' value='Edit photo' onclick=\"return launchEditor('image1', '$fulltarget');\" /></p>";

?>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have this in your code: echo "..html... "..." ..more html..". The problem here is that when the parser encounters the second " (after html... in this case), it thinks: 'hey! this is the end of echo, so i can assume that the echo is done here, but what you actually want is to tell the parser to ignore the two " you have in your code. thus you need to escape the quotes. you escape the " using . To be something like:
 **onclick=\"return launchEditor('image1', '$fulltarget');\"**

"an another problem too here please..: Notice: Undefined index: sub in C:\xampp\htdocs\uploader\upload.php on line 4 also one another Notice: Undefined variable: fulltarget in C:\xampp\htdocs\uploader\upload.php on line 100 Notice: Undefined variable: fulltarget in C:\xampp\htdocs\uploader\upload.php on line 100"

Well, for the first part of the problem, you are always assuming that 'sub' exists in $_POST. But, what if it does not? In this case your post data does not contain 'sub'. That is what the parser is telling you. It is always a good approach to do a

```
if(isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    $subject = $_POST['sub']
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

This way you are ensuring that 'sub' actually exists before trying to access it out of post.

Comment: an another problem too here please..: `Notice: Undefined index: sub in C:\xampp\htdocs\uploader\upload.php on line 4` also one another `Notice: Undefined variable: fulltarget in C:\xampp\htdocs\uploader\upload.php on line 100 Notice: Undefined variable: fulltarget in C:\xampp\htdocs\uploader\upload.php on line 100`

Comment: sure..great can you give me the correct code for this please..so that i replace it there...

Comment: We can help you solve a problem in your code, but cant rewrite the whole code for you :-)

Comment: wow! you did not accept the answer because we did not give you code? Your original question was answered though! It is spooky to see an answer go from accepted to not accepted because a follow up question was not answered.

Comment: i will accept your answer if you give me the correct code..though i added the one you just give about sub and got other errors...so confusing that's why i am asking for quick code please..!

Comment: the original question you asked was "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\uploader\upload.php on line 100" - which was resolved.

Comment: i edited the question please..now please you can answer my new question...!

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to go if you do not want to escape...

```
<?php //any php code
<<<HTML //html and php variables 
<p><input type='image' src='http://images.aviary.com/images/edit-photo.png' value='Edit photo' onclick="return launchEditor('image1', '$fulltarget');" /></p>";   
HTML;
?>
```

your variables are executed without an echo in this case.

Comment: an another problem too here please..: `Notice: Undefined index: sub in C:\xampp\htdocs\uploader\upload.php` on line 4 also one another `Notice: Undefined variable: fulltarget in C:\xampp\htdocs\uploader\upload.php on line 100 Notice: Undefined variable: fulltarget in C:\xampp\htdocs\uploader\upload.php on line 100`

Comment: for me <<<HTML HTML; oppening and closing tags are much better than an echo since it is a bunch of HTML u got there + this way you do not have to escape ' or "

Comment: place <<<HTML on line 61 of ur file and check it out